# Is it a bug that the /sites route always returns zero for total?

Tags: bug, api-v2.2

I want to know how many Stack Exchange sites there are.
Querying http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites, using a filter that makes `total` appear, I find that the value is always zero.

For example,
          http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?filter=!6P-i5S514Gfnl

Responds:

```
{ "total": 0 }
```

Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: BTW, I did find the workaround -- pagesize is unbounded for sites so I just did a request with pagesize=5000 and counted the number of items returned which is 340 at the moment.

Comment: Confirmed. That's a bug.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, and for edits. It's a little odd, though, how the new title for this ends in a question mark despite not being phrased as a question? ;-)

Comment: BTW, that's not 340 sites.  It's 170 sites, plus their *metas* (with 2 exceptions and not counting Area 51).